# Changing a table in DBML file throws error

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I had to add a new column to my table so I did that in the database and then I removed the table from the dbml file and readded the one with the new column. So the column I added was (_isActive bit null allowed) and this messed up my designer file. It has added a duplicate definition of some of the attributes like: private bool *isActive and other one as private System.Nullable @*_isActive; Also added additional stuff. I had to delete the designer file and reload it with old one. How should I go to make this change in the dbml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq-To-SQL I believe you need to use the designer to remove and add a table after you have made a schema change.

If you edited the code-behind file, those changes can cause problems. There is a reason all the classes there are defiend as `partial class`

So, I suspect your best option is to delete your DBML and start again.